# What are the differences between Defense of the Ancients (DotA) and DOTA 2?

Tags: dota-2, version-differences, dota

Seeing that [The International tournament](http://www.dota2.com/tournaments/international/) has finished (and therefore DOTA 2 previewed) are any DOTA users able to list the differences/similarities? -- I'm sure Valve wanted to stay true, but have they?
(Ignoring the beautiful new graphics, non warcraft 3 mod and network connectivity improvements)

Comment: FYI, I think we've decided that questions like this should wait until there is at least a beta that is available to members of the general public (even if it is a closed beta).  See http://meta.gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/2512/when-is-it-ok-to-start-talking-about-new-games

Comment: You can't access the secret shop from Roshan's platform. That's the only change I saw from the streams I watched.

Comment: @bwarner Should it be re-opened when the beta starts? or closed once the beta begins?

Comment: @David Yah, I had a similar question about Diablo 3, and the thought was to close it now and re-open it once the beta starts.

Comment: @bwarner, makes sense although certainly from the answers provided thus far the question I believe a definitive answer can be selected...that being said, i guess it could change hence why the question should be closed.

Comment: I think we should avoid speculation when ever possible.  I can't see this question having anything but speculative answers at this point...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are virtually no differences. It's almost an exact copy of the original Warcraft 3 map, minus the improved graphics, down to the very level of the basic controls itself (animation cancelling, etc.).

The biggest difference that you'll feel while playing it is the matchmaking system which Dota2 will take from games like Team Fortress 2 and Left 4 Dead and a ranking system about which we don't know much yet.

I'd love to give sources on this, but I'm afraid I don't have ones on hand right now. There aren't exactly a ton of interviews on the game, and most of this stuff is gathered from simply watching the game (it looks like it's an exact copy) and posts by icefrog (one of the original Dota caretakers who now works on the game) on various forums.

Comment: Valve will do some kind of item shop with DOTA2 no doubt, so that's a big difference right there.

Comment: I seriously doubt that. The guys behind the game are smart enough to know that such things upset the games balance immensely. I assume they will keep such things to alternative costumes, or like League of Legends where all characters are available in principle, but on a random basis and if you want to play one constantly you have to buy it for money or for ingame-points that you earned. Gabe Newell even said that they have no monetization plans yet whatsoever. They could just go the "full-prize" route and keep it free of game changing DLC entirely (like Left 4 Dead which only had new maps)

Comment: Err.. I'll say only TF2 and hats..

Comment: Do they do something in the game other than look pretty?

Comment: @heishe No.  I think that's what yx_ was talking about.  The hats you can buy in TF2 which do nothing.

Comment: that's exactly what I meant

Comment: After playing the beta for a while, I can confidently say that there are quite a few differences between the two games that are more than cosmetic.

Comment: Feel free to add an answer and list the differences :-) In that case I'll delete my answer since it's incorrect.

Comment: I didn't play Dota1 seriously so doing so would require me to check everything I'm not sure about offhand. Some simple and obvious ones though are increased turn rates and different tower aggro.

Answer (score 5):

The graphics are far from what you call beautiful nowdays,game has better poly-count(more rounded and sharper 3D objects)but the textures are low on details what gives the game the carton look(team fortress 2 is also good example...LoL and borderlands added outline which adds comic like feel).

What i'm trying to say is that valve made it on purpose to look more like warcraft 3 graphics which uses low detail textures since it is older game.If they wanted to use all their graphic advantages over Warcraft 3 the game would look more like heroes of newerth.

Also icefrog stated that he wanted to make game with simple effects so that all that multicolored flashing spells don't confuse the players in team fights.

The non w3 mod and network are the whole point of making a new game,bunch of players that  moved from warcraft 3 to LoL or HoN is because they offer better online experience with all the statistic tracking and mostly that they eliminate leavers from games.

The models,items,buildings... had to be tweaked due to copyright on warcraft 3.

Edit:For now before new updates take place(to balance gameplay,new heroes...)The gameplay (heroes,items and spells) remain the same.There are slight glitches tho,when you make new game it makes it hard to mimic the units(time,dmg,range) from other games so the gameplay might be bit faster or slower,and certain heroes and spells have different video effect and the "casting times" can't be the same...But in general it does not matter much to a player since that values are very small(parts of a secod).

...Basicly they couldn't have stayed more true to original dota without making exactly the same game.

[Link to bigger image](http://dota2strategyguide.com/wp-content/uploads/2011/08/comparison-dota-dota2-lol-hon.jpg)

[image]

Comment: Good points...i wanted to ignore graphics/network to highlgiht gameplay perhaps...the water in the middle is beautiful :)

Comment: oh,I ignored the "ignore" xD.Edited the post a bit and added graphic comparison.

Comment: The graphic does suggest a clear sticking to the original format...

Answer (score 4):

Same game, different user experience. As far as I see:

1. Only one shop in base. Because we no longer play DOTA in Warcraft 3, whose mod has some limitations, one shop can sell as many items as Valve wants, so why not only keep on shop?
2. Another improvement in shopping is that now player can see how to combine items to upgrade to new item, and can directly buy the upgraded item if has enough gold.
3. HP bar are separated into segments. every 1K HP is a long segment, while 250 HP is a short segment. It's easier for player to know how many HP your enemy have, thus can choose whether or when to use skills.
4. Now you can draw in mini map, which I don't know whether we can do in DOTA 1.
5. Another big difference is in OB system. OB system in DOTA 2 is one of the best in the world. Almost every statistics data you are interested in can be found during OB a game. And you can see player's first person perspective.
6. There are some interesting features in Hall. Reading blogs, news, update info, etc; Study on heroes and items; watch games of course, and so on.

There are more improvements in DotA 2 but I can only quickly remember the above 6, which I guess are most impressive ones for me.

Answer (score 1):

There is already a difference on the game, **Luna** for example can now wield Desolator or Skadi in DotA2.

Answer (score 0):

According to my reliable source, http://wiki.teamliquid.net/dota2/Dota_History and http://www.gosugamers.net/dota/features/2791-history-of-dota,

The earliest version of the game that we now call "Dota 2" was released in 2003 by the game designer "Eul" under the name of "Dota 2". However, I can argue that the first Dota 2, the one released in 2002, can be termed as Dota 1 or Dota without 2 because enter image description here This was basically a game that had been recently developed from the Warcraft 3: The Frozen Throne (TFT) that came out on July 1st, 2003.[image]

The true version of Dota 2, as we know it today, probably started to take its form after the gamer developers Meian and Ragn0r made the version of Eul into the first version of the game called "DotA Allstars Beta v0.95" that was released on February 3, 2004.[image]

DotA Allstars v.4.0a was released on April 26, 2004. It was the first version to feature Roshan. Guinsoo is the new developer that joined in the fun in 2004 to improve Dota 2 with more patches and updates.[image]

[image]
On February 28th 2005, Guinsoo the developer left, and Neichus and IceFrog officially took over development from 6.01 continuing the process of improving DotA.enter image description here From here, I think it is clear that DotA was not intended to be a separate version of DotA 2, but a gradually consistent updates and modding transformed it from a just a mod of World of Warcraft into a game we now recognize and love in 2015.[image]

Interesting note: Eul's Scepter of Divinity and Guinsoo's Scythe of Vyse are in-game items that were originally named after the previous DotA developers GuinSoo and Eul. Roshan, Dota 2's most well known boss-scale monster, was named after Guinsoo's bowling ball.

Comment: I have never played the first version (Dota 1), which is still available online if you search for "Dota 1" in Google, that looks much like World of Warcraft, but I heard it is very different from the Dota 2; especially the missing and evasion part + missing ranged hits up the cliffs / inclines.